# Google Appengine: query object suddenly becomes list object without query attributes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cursor

I get this:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

on this line:

```
company_cursor = companies.cursor()
```

when running the following code:

```
q = Company.all()
q.order("datetime")
companies = q.fetch(5)

company_cursor = memcache.get("company_cursor")

if company_cursor:
    companies.with_cursor(start_cursor = company_cursor)

for company in companies: 
    do_stuff(company)

company_cursor = companies.cursor() 
memcache.set("company_cursor",company_cursor, 11000)
```

As far as I can see, my code looks like the example shown here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is `q`, but `fetch` on a query returns a list of entities, so `companies` is in fact a list.

To have the cursor be part of the query, you need to add it before running fetch.

Comment: that works, but won't the cursor now be at the end of all companies, rather than at the end of the five i fetch?

Comment: You want to use q.with_cursor before the fetch, then q.get_cursor() afterwards

Comment: that works, with .cursor(), not .get_cursor(). as a follow-up: how do i reset the cursor to before the first company in the query?